# Walk around square platform. Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to make a character that walks around a platform and if the character reach a corner, it rotates and continue walking on the side of the platform, same with the bottom part.

This is a visual representation of what I'm trying to achive.
[Movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUBhy.png)

The specific problem is when the character reach the corners, the rotation just go crazy. I'm trayng to achive this using a raycast from the character to the platform and if the raycast doesn't find floor, I start the rotation like this:

```
times++;
 transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,Quaternion.AngleAxis(times*-89.9f,Vector3.forward),Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
 _characterGravity.SetGravityAngle(transform.localEulerAngles.z);
```

I'm using a characterGravity script that allows me to change the gravity direction for the character in order to not fall when is walking upside down or on the sides. But this is not working propperly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is a 2D side-view (platformer) game?

Comment: @rodamn yes it is

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 2D view is aligned on the X-Y plane, with the Z-axis aimed into the screen (the same direction the camera is facing), I suggest using [`Transform.Rotate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) instead of trying to linearly interpolate the rotation between two values:

```
  if (ShouldRotateAroundCorner()) {
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
  }
```

You'll just need to make sure your ShouldRotateAroundCorner() knows when to start and stop the 90 degree turn, which will take a little bit of additional code to keep track of when it's in this state change.